# My CSS doesn't work, except for one page in my website

Tags: html, css

I just started learning webdesign and I'm having this ongoing problem and I've posted a question about it before. Everything I tried didn't work but I made a few changes so I wanted to rephrase the question and add some more details.

I'm making a simple website for a Romanian artist and it will have an English version and a Romanian version (switching languages with tiny flags in the nav bar).

It's all written in WordPad, using just html and css, and all pages are in the same root folder. I have several html files and one css file (so it's an external file), which is linked in the head of each page. I have English versions and Romanian versions and they're all linked accordingly from the navigation.

Now, my issue is that the CSS will only work on the main English page and refuses to on any of the others, no matter which language, despite all of them having the same head, header and footer structure.

I tried Firefox and Chrome and it's the same story.

I clicked on "Page Source" on all the pages when opened in a browser, corrected any errors showing up, and the link to the css and all pages works when I click it.

I initially had several CSS files, one for each html file, but I deleted them except for one (I misunderstood the process initially and didn't realize they can all have the same css file). So now there is only one CSS file in the root folder "Style.css".

All html files are saved in "Unicode" encoding.

Except for the modified words, this is the exact css, as well as html structure of the main English page (on which the CSS works):

```css
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

address {
    float: right;
}

article.figures figure {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    Font-family: Verdana;
}

footer {
    color: grey;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Name</title>

  <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Name, visual artist">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Name, visual artist, abstract, painting, fine art">
  <meta name="author" content="Me">

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <img src="images\paint logo.jpg" width="150" height="110" alt="artists logo">
    <h1>Name </h1>


    <nav>
      <a href=///C:/Users/.../main page in English.html>Galleries</a>
      <a href=file:///C:/Users/.../News.html>News</a>
      <a href=file:///C:/Users/.../About.html>About</a>
      <a href="http://www.saatchiart.com/...">Shop</a>


      <a href="file:///C:/Users/.../webpageinRomanian.html">
        <img src="images\romanian flag.jpg" width="20" height="15" alt="Romanian">
      </a>
    </nav>

  </header>





  <address>email</address>


  <article class="figures">

    <figure>
      <img src="images\painting.jpg" width="335" height="325" alt="painting">
      <figcaption>Paintings from 2010 - 2015</figcaption>
    </figure>



    <figure>
      <img src="images\2.jpg" width="335" height="325" alt="painting 2">
      <figcaption>2009 - 2000</figcaption>
    </figure>



    <figure>
      <img src="images\3.jpg" width="335" height="325" alt="painting 3">
      <figcaption>1990 - 1999</figcaption>
    </figure>

  </article>




  <footer>copyright Name
    <br>

    <A HREF="https://www.facebook./...">
      <IMG SRC="images/fb logo.png" width="30" height="30" ALT="Facebook">
    </A>
    <A HREF="https://www.behance....">
      <IMG SRC="images/behance logo.png" width="30" height="30" ALT="Behance">
    </A>
    <br>Webdesign by me
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

This is a page on which the same CSS doesn't work:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
address {
  float: right;
}
article.figures figure {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
aside {
  float: right;
  Font-family: Verdana;
}
footer {
  color: grey;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Name News</title>

  <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Name, visual artist">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Name, visual artist, abstract, painting, fine art">
  <meta name="author" content="Me">

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <img src="images\paint logo.jpg" width="150" height="110" alt="artists logo">
    <h1>Name </h1>


    <nav>
    <a href=///C:/Users/.../main page in English.html>Galleries</a>
      <a href=file:///C:/Users/.../News.html>News</a>
      <a href=file:///C:/Users/.../About.html>About</a>
      <a href="http://www.saatchiart.com/...">Shop</a>



      <a href="file:///C:/Users/.../webpageinRomanian.html">
        <img src="images\romanian flag.jpg" width="20" height="15" alt="Romanian">
      </a>
    </nav>

  </header>





  <address>email</address>


  <h2>What's New</h2>

  <h3>Upcoming exhibitions:</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>July 2016</li>
    <li>October 2016</li>
  </ul>




  <footer>copyright Name
    <br>

    <A HREF="https://www.facebook./...">
      <IMG SRC="images/fb logo.png" width="30" height="30" ALT="Facebook">
    </A>
    <A HREF="https://www.behance....">
      <IMG SRC="images/behance logo.png" width="30" height="30" ALT="Behance">
    </A>
    <br>Webdesign by me
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Which might work on this website, but I swear, it won't work in my browsers.

It's driving me nuts.

I'd be extremely grateful for any help!

EDIT:
This is what shows up in the developers console for the 'News' page:
[image]

[image]

And this is the root folder:
[image]

Comment: i bet that this have something to do with the locations of your files inside your working directory.. and link can't have href attribute with C:\ paths

Comment: It's great that you're starting to develop. It would be nice if you cleared your code a bit and formatted it a bit better so it's easier to spot mistakes.

Comment: The situation you are describing should not cause this issue. But a quick glance in the developer console (F12) should point out any issues the browser has with finding or loading your CSS. If not - feel free to post a link to the WiP site.

Comment: Would it be possible to see a screencap of your folder/file structure?

Comment: @ymz Corrected that - thank you! Still doesn't work though...

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes It is pointing out that there IS something wrong with the CSS, I think, but I can't really make out what exactly it is...

Comment: @JesseKernaghan Yes, added it

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside your `<head>`

[Source: w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

```html
<base href="http://www.yourwebsite/" target="_blank">
```

Comment: A moment.. I see screenshots now

Answer (score 1):

Well it is working for me... make sure that the html and css files actually are in the same folder

```
/folder
--thing.html
--other.html
--style.css
```

And as pointed out in comment don't use c:/ to referer to files